# Visual Studio - Build Agent - Xcode - Error Code 65 (Build Failure)

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, build, agent

I have just tried to setup a Build Agent on my Mac to build a Xcode SWIFT project I am playing around with. I have got the build agent working on an android studio project on my Windows machine, but I can't seem to get SWIFT project to build.

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwiftSources normal armv7 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(1 failure)
Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
```

Is anyone else experiencing this while using Visual Studio Build Agents?

Xcode - 8.3.3

I am not trying to sign anything, just build the IPA file to begin with.

Thanks!